# fine and fast csv reader

Tags: c#, .net, file, csv

I m using Lumenworks CSV reader and i must say i m not very happy with it with how it works so far.

I m parsing thousands of csv files within an hour and there is always a problem, either throws an exception complaining about bad records or skewing the columns etc.

Can you recommend a fine CSV reader, it doesnt have to be a free one, but bug free.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain the input files are really CSV? Do you have the option of importing the files into a database and then using the data? For example, MS SQL bulk import can easily handle various kinds of CSV files and it would take a few seconds to import extremely large files. From that point forward you're just working for data in a database table.

Comment: i have to parse the files and process them. i cant do bulk insert to db. while parsin, lumenworks craps a lot for everylittle thing.

Comment: I agree...lumen always throws exceptions...all we need is simple reader who reads delimited lines, no fancy crap...only read damn lines ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the input files.I think these tool don't stop at format check because they aim for quantity stuff (skiping erroneous data to treat the maximum of files).
In the real world you rarely see a stream of clean CSV. Drivers tend to give their own kind:

-no quotes

-semi colon instead of comma

Files that are generating errors usually come from the same source.

Comment: As Frank V suggested you have to isolate the wrong files. Are your CSV coming from MS Access, a database export or custom made? The correct filetypes should follow CSV as specified in the standard

Answer (score 3):

FileHelpers Open Source Library http://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: @user177883, Can you post the error it is returning in your original question?

Comment: you can pass an option to ignore the errors. which makes it work. but it s very very slow.

Comment: this is a very slow library, lumenworks is much faster than this.

Answer (score 3):

Try [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a library I maintain). It's also available on NuGet.

Comment: I just did some quick testing, and this was slower than FileHelpers and Lumenworks.

Answer (score 1):

You cite that you are receiving exceptions and such from the files. While these may be undesired, have you investigated the cause?

You might just want to use one of the current parsers that are on the table and when an exception occurs, try an alternative or/and handle the scenarios with custom code. I know it's not exactly what you are looking for but the problem may not be the tools you are using but the input the tools are receiving...

You could also move the offending file to a separate directory (in code) to look at a bit later and get what will process, processed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSV parser built into .NET.

From http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/:

```
// TextFieldParser is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace.
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
    parser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
    parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    // Skip over header line.
    parser.ReadLine();

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        yield return new Brand()
        {
            Name = fields[0],
            FactoryLocation = fields[1],
            EstablishedYear = int.Parse(fields[2]),
            Profit = double.Parse(fields[3], swedishCulture)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The VB.Net parser is much slower than the Lumenworks parser however. In our tests the Lumenworks parser was ~20 - 60 faster.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a long time since I used it, but [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) does CSV parsing with lots of options.

Comment: define craps out... some type of specific error, is there something unusual with the CSV file that blow up?

Comment: craps out = crashes! lol jk. even though filehelpers is recommended by alot of people I've heard some negative reviews as well, so not surprised...